# Jenkins TFS integration

Tags: jenkins, tfs, integration

I am trying to integrate TFS with Jenkins. I passed following parameters:

> http://10.5.5.206:8080/tfs
>   $/SampleApp/New Folder/AspDotNet
>   UserName: TFS server User Name
>   Password: TFS Server Password

But I am getting following error while Building

> Started by user anonymous
>       Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TFS-    CheckOut\workspace
>       Deleting workspace as the configuration has changed since a build was     performed on this computer.
>       [workspace] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TFS-  CheckOut\workspace\tf.exe" workspaces -format:brief
>   -server:http://10.5.5.206:8080/tfs ********
>       Collection: http://10.5.5.206:8080/tfs
>       Workspace                  Owner         Computer   Comment
>
> ---
>
> ```
> Hudson-TFS-CheckOut-MASTER Administrator WIN-DEVOPS 
> [workspace] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TFS-    CheckOut\workspace\tf.exe" workspace -delete
> ```
>
> Hudson-TFS-CheckOut-MASTER;WIN-  FIGHT\Administrator -noprompt
>   -server:http://10.5.5.206:8080/tfs ********
>       [workspace] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TFS- CheckOut\workspace\tf.exe" workspace -new
>   Hudson-TFS-CheckOut-MASTER;WIN-FIGHT\Administrator -noprompt
>   -server:http://10.5.5.206:8080/tfs ********
>       [workspace] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TFS-CheckOut\workspace\tf.exe" workfold -map
>   "$/SampleApp/New Folder/AspDotNet" "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TFS-CheckOut\workspace"
>   -workspace:Hudson-TFS-CheckOut-MASTER -server:http://10.5.5.206:8080/tfs ********
>       [workspace] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TFS-CheckOut\workspace\tf.exe" get . -recursive
>   -version:D2015-04-16T15:25:23Z -noprompt ********
>       All files are up to date.
>       [workspace] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TFS-CheckOut\workspace\tf.exe" history
>   "$/SampleApp/New Folder/AspDotNet" -recursive -stopafter:1 -noprompt
>   -version:D2015-04-16T15:25:24Z -format:brief ******** -server:http://10.5.5.206:8080/tfs
>       No history entries were found for the item and version combination specified. FATAL: For input string: ""
>       java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""     at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)    at
>   hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Project.getRemoteChangesetVersion(Project.java:209)
>     at
>   hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Project.getRemoteChangesetVersion(Project.java:223)
>     at
>   hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm.checkout(TeamFoundationServerScm.java:189)
>     at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1270)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:609)
>     at
>   jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:531)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)  at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
>       Finished: FAILURE

Please help.

Comment: Why integrate with Jenkins rather than the built in build system...

Comment: I need it for automating the process. This automation contains further steps as well. That's why Jenkins. Could you help?

Comment: Why can't you call those automations from PowerShell in TF Build? If the answer is "because I want to dam it" then that's OK too, I just wanted to understand the value of the added complexity of using Jenkins?